# SQL: Find column names for select by XML definition

Tags: sql, xml, sql-server-2008, unpivot

I have two tables in SQL server 2008:

```
Definitions(ID, XML)
Data(DataID, DefinitionID, COL1, COL2, ..)
```

XML looks like this:

```
<definition>
    <field columnname="COL1" fieldname="FirstName" />
    <field columnname="COL2" fieldname="Surname" />
</definition>
```

What I need is something like this:

```
DataID, Surname, FirstName
1       Adams    Adam     
2       Llama    John     
3       Kenny    Lorna
```

**I was trying to use cross apply to get columns from xml and unpivot to get data from datatable - but cannot get them merged together... is there any sane method for this?**

What I was trying:

```
select distinct 
       Ids.Id.value('@columnname', 'nvarchar(50)') as ide,
       Ids.Id.value('@fieldname', 'nvarchar(50)') as name
   from Definitions 
   cross apply Xml.nodes('//field') as Ids(id)
```

and:

```
select col, value from 
   (SELECT COL1, COL2  FROM Data) d
   UNPIVOT 
   (value for col IN (COL1, COL2)) AS newdata
;
```

Comment: So you want the definition to controle the column names, the number of columns and from what column the data should be fetched from?

Comment: Do you want to use more than one definition in one query or is the query parametrized with the definition you want to use?

Comment: Ideal would be kind of "view" with Data distributed to column names... it have to be more then one definition in one query, but:
Its for reporting mostly so if there is no other way I can iterate through cursor with definitions and even filter columns later by hand.

`First I just need to generate view for one row :)`

Problem is - col1 could be "Surname" in one Data row and "FirstName" in other... (it is consumer defined data)

Comment: If you have a variable number of columns and/or variable column names in the output you need to build your query dynamically using the XML definition as input. Is it so or do you know when writing the query what columns you need and you just have to figure out (using the XML) in what column to look for the data?

Comment: yes, I do know when writing the query what columns I need and just have to figure out (using the XML) in what column to look for the data

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `case` to check the XML for what column you should use.

```
select D.DataID,
       case DD.XML.value('(/definition/field[@fieldname="FirstName"]/@columnname)[1]', 'sysname')
         when 'COL1' then D.COL1
         when 'COL2' then D.COL2
       end as FirstName,
       case DD.XML.value('(/definition/field[@fieldname="Surname"]/@columnname)[1]', 'sysname')
         when 'COL1' then D.COL1
         when 'COL2' then D.COL2
       end as Surname
from Data as D
  inner join Definitions as DD
    on D.DefinitionID = DD.ID
```